# Grid-template-areas grow when condition is false

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

```
export const AboutRow = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: minmax(auto,1fr);
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-areas: ${({ imgStart }) =>
    imgStart ? "'col2 col1'" : "'col1 col2'"};

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    grid-template-areas: ${({ imgStart }) =>
      imgStart ? "'col1' 'col2'" : "'col1 col1' 'col2 col2"};
  } ;
`;
```

When imgStart is true both areas are the same size but when imgStart false right area grows. How can I fix this?[image: This is when imgStart false]
[image: This is when imgStart true]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want col1 and col2 same size even when imgStart is false. But when imgStart is false Right area grows.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)